# Is the `_ansible_parent_role_name` variable name reserved in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

When I try to use `_ansible_parent_role_name` as a variable name (with the `set_fact` module), I get the following error message:

```
ERROR! invalid parameter specified for action 'set_fact': '_ansible_parent_role_name'
```

Is it reserved?

Ansible version is 2.9.6.

At the same time, the `ansible_parent_role_name` and `__ansible_parent_role_name` names are fine. [Searching](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=_ansible_parent_role_name) for any mentions of `_ansible_parent_role_name` through the source code gives nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything starting with `_ansible_` or `ansible_` should be considered reserved, and `_ansible` is reserved for internal variables that are never set by the user. No modules can be called with parameters starting with `_ansible_`: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/400475acc033ea146c8dc4929e347166ee85c0e6/lib/ansible/parsing/mod_args.py#L179-L185

Comment: Thanks a lot! Alas, it doesn't seem to be documented (or this is my inattentiveness).